# Postgres transaction isolation between databases on same sever

Tags: postgresql, transactions

We are experiencing a problem on a Postgres instance where one long running transaction on one database prevent the vacuum process to remove dead tuples on a tables of another database (of the same instance).

It seems crazy to me that xmin is shared cross database.

So here are my questions :

- Is that a normal behavior or did we misconfigured something ?
- Why is it so ?
- Is there a workaround ?

Thanks folks

postgres version 12.4

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: @jjanes version 12.4

Comment: I can't reproduce this on 12.4.  If the long running transaction is in the same database it blocks cleanup, but not if it is in a different database of the same cluster.  Do you have a simple reproducer?  I'd also note 12.4 has a substantial number of known bugs, 12.11 is the latest.

Comment: @bokan did you get any further with your investigation? I'm fairly sure we've just seen the same thing on PG 14.4 but I haven't yet investigated further

Comment: @owst : I did nothing more on this, I should try to reproduce it on a new instance. Please report anything you found here

Comment: @bokan I've started looking at this again... I've got a lead, which is that having `hot_standby_feedback = on` seems to be causing the issue. Do you by any chance have that setting enabled?

Comment: @owst: yes it is on, and it makes sense

Comment: @owst : can you make it an answer so I can accept it and we can document it for others ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this issue using PG 14.4 when the `hot_standby_feedback` setting was `on`, but not when it was `off`.

I asked on the PG mailing list where [it was confirmed as expected](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/8f1be0222b943a6fc99e7ef6283bd144d2d3447a.camel%40cybertec.at)

> There is only one "backend_xmin" in "pg_stat_replication", which corresponds to the snapshot held by the oldest query in any database on the standby server.

Unfortunately there was no response to my followup questions on the mailing list, but at least the behaviour was confirmed as expected.